# Google Cloud Message uniqueness of registration_id

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've read Google Cloud Messaging documentation about GCM key (registration_id) and it is not clear enough uniqueness of it. Is it unique for device + application pair?

The case is - I store a table of devices keys on my server and I want to delete records just by key (and NOT by pair user id + key).

I'm a little bit confused by the following sentence:

> Unregistration and re-registration may each take up to five minutes to propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due to the unregistered state, and messages may go to the wrong user
>    https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

Does it mean that token can be assign to another user?

Answer (score 0):

The FCM/GCM token is surely unique.

Otherwise a message sent to one device would go to multiple devices of different people.

But using it as a primary key or for identification is not recommended.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the following sentence: 

Unregistration and re-registration may each take up to five minutes to propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due to the unregistered state, and messages may go to the wrong user -  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

That is why I've asked question about uniqueness

Comment: Strange but that should not happen. Message going to a wrong user is a very critical issue and I'm sure Google takes privacy seriously. But it is still not a good idea to use it as an identifier.

Comment: Why do you think so? (not a good idea to use it as an identifier)

Comment: Because it may change, even for a single device. User may uninstall and reinstall app or clear app data.